# ¿Como cambiar el tamaño de un JFrame con un ActionListener implementado en otra clase?

Tags: java

queria poder cambiar el tamaño de una ventana al pulsar un boton, lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Ventana1 extends JFrame{

public Ventana1(){
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(300,300);
JButton boton = new JButton();
add(boton);


ActionListener oyente = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setSize(500,500);
    }
};
boton.addActionListener(oyente);}


public static void main(String[] args) {
   Ventana1 v1 = new Ventana1();
   v1.setVisible(true);
}}
```

y funciona pero despues en un ejercicio en el que el ActionListener es implementado por una clase intente hacer lo mismo sin exito:

```
public class Ventana2 extends JFrame{

public Ventana2(){
    setSize(300,300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton boton = new JButton();
    add(boton);

    oyenteboton oyente = new oyenteboton();
    boton.addActionListener(oyente);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Ventana2 v2 = new Ventana2();
    v2.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

```
class oyenteboton implements ActionListener{

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    setSize(400,400);
}
```

}

¿Como podria hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta modificar "boton.addActionListener(oyente);" el "oyente" por la palabra clave **this**. boton.addActionListener(this);